# How do I start a blank project in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to the Ionic Framework, very new, and I wanted to start a new project, but every time I start a new project it autodownloads the tabs sample as my project. I want a blank new project, how can I stop Ionic from downloading the tabs sample, because as it is I'm not sure which files to remove without breaking anything.

Comment: Actually there are 3 examples in the Getting Started page: http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/ in step 2. Good luck and read documentation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this command to start a new blank app with the name "myApp":

`ionic start myApp blank`

Answer (score 0):

What command do you use to create the project?

Have you tried:

```
ionic start myApp blank
```

[You should read the doc:](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple:
`ionic start APP_NAME blank`.
Or you want to specify more information:
`ionic start -a APP_NAME -i PACKAGE_NAME FOLDER_NAME blank`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just follow this steps and you will able to open a blank project in ionic. 
Open the terminal and write

npm install -g ionic

then next command is

ionic start myApp blank  ( myApp is the project name you want to create ) for example

ionic start fashion blank  ( So here I want to create an app for e-commerce and my project name is fashion )

I hope this will work for you.